# Como verificar se IP existe com bat

Tags: batch

Consigo pingar todos os endereços da rede com algo semelhante a isso:

```
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 100) do ping 10.1.1.%%x
```

Porém, nem todos os endereços são válidos, e nesses caso, ele da timeout. Tem alguma maneira de eu verificar se o IP existe, para somente então pinga-lo?

Explicando mais detalhadamente, segue exemplo do que eu queria fazer mais ou menos (em uma linguagem de exemplo)

```
for(int i = 1; i < 256; i++)
{
    var ip = formataip(i);
    if(ip_existe(ip))
       ping_ip(ip);
}
```

Comment: Acho que o jeito mais fácil talvez seria filtrar os que derem timeout e somente exibir os que responderem a um primeiro ping.

Comment: Se está online. Se o ping não da Timeout.

Comment: @EMBarbosa pois é, conforme fui pesquisando, fui percebendo isso também, por isso só estava deixando a pergunta mais um tempo sem resposta aceita para ver se havia alguma maneira obscura kkk

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> maneira obscura kkk

Não sei o quanto obscuro é isso, mas tudo indica que pela RFC, pacotes `TCP ACK` não solicitados deveriam ser respondidos com `TCP RST` (conexão recusada), o que pode ser "abusado" (e é) por programas que fazem scan de rede, conhecidos como SYN SCANs.

Eles começam um `handshake` mas não terminam - só analisam a resposta do `host`.

Existem vários destes, um deles é da própria Microsoft, e se chama [psping](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psping.aspx).

Usando o seguinte .bat:

```
@echo off
for /L %%a in (1,1,255) do (
   psping -n 2 192.168.10.%%a:3389
)
```

Note o uso da porta do `remote desktop`, 3389 - eu consegui resposta de `hosts` windows e mac que tinham o serviço habilitado e desabilitado.

```
TCP connect to 192.168.20.26:3389:
3 iterations (warmup 1) ping test:
Connecting to 192.168.20.26:3389 (warmup): from 0.0.0.0:63028:
The remote computer refused the network connection.
```

> Neste caso, se o computador está **recusando** a conexão, podemos supor que ele existe... xD

E no caso deste velho amigo meu, que bloqueia ICMP:

```
Pinging 192.168.10.200 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
```

Ele não esperava por isso:

```
PsPing v2.10 - PsPing - ping, latency, bandwidth measurement utility
Copyright (C) 2012-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
TCP connect to 192.168.10.200:3389:
11 iterations (warmup 1) ping test:
Connecting to 192.168.10.200:3389 (warmup): from 192.168.10.192:63049: 0.64ms
Connecting to 192.168.10.200:3389: from 192.168.10.192:63050: 0.47ms
Connecting to 192.168.10.200:3389: from 192.168.10.192:63051: 0.54ms
Connecting to 192.168.10.200:3389: from 192.168.10.192:63052: 0.53ms
Connecting to 192.168.10.200:3389: from 192.168.10.192:63053: 0.54ms
Connecting to 192.168.10.200:3389: from 192.168.10.192:63054: 0.53ms
```

> Essa técnica não funcionará sempre, obviamente - e é possível testar outras portas (eu, particularmente não tive sorte com elas), mas dizem que os SYN SCANs tem... ;)

Fontes:
[ping alternative for tcp?](https://serverfault.com/questions/14376/ping-alternative-for-tcp)
[Netcat Power Tools](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=SyXFg6uMLykC&pg=PA68&lpg=PA68&dq=tcp+ping+netcat&source=bl&ots=TZp82pfDvY&sig=ksj76eZewoaPpKN9yBJ8PPoex-0&hl=en&ei=B7UfSsLrAofhtgfS2qGuBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=tcp%20ping%20netcat&f=false)

Comment: Interessante! Então o host pode estar online, mas mesmo assim não aceitar minha conexão! Acho que vou precisar disso também, muito obrigado!

Comment: @ArturoTemplário A diferença é que o psping implementa um ping pra TCP e o programa ping implementa para ICMP. E o host/servidor pode ser configurado para fazer qualquer coisa, como ignorar comunicação ICMP ou TCP, ignorar certas portas ou recusar certas portas.

Answer (score 8):

Uma sugestão é efetuar o comando `ping` e procurar por uma string na resposta.

**Por exemplo:**

Quando o ping é executado com sucesso é retornado algo como `Resposta de 10.1.1.1: bytes=32 tempo<1ms TTL=255` e quando há erro algo como `Esgotado o tempo limite do pedido.` e etc...

Neste caso, se a string de resposta contiver algo como `TTL=` quer dizer que o `ping` foi executado com sucesso. Assim sendo podemos utilizar o código abaixo para analisar o retorno no comando:

```
@echo off
set "host=10.1.1"
setlocal
for /L %%I in (1,1,10) do (
    ping -n 1 -w 1000 %host%.%%I | find /i "TTL=" >NUL && (
        echo %host%.%%I: ONLINE
    ) || (
        echo %host%.%%I OFFLINE
    )
)
pause
```

No código acima o número de requisições foi limitada a apenas uma com `ping -n 1` e o tempo limite de espera para cada resposta 1000ms com `ping -w 1000`. Para saber mais digite `ping /?`.

Comment: Só não dá certo quando o servidor é bloqueado para Ping. Mas acho que isso já é neura demais da minha parte

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Sim, se for bloqueado para ping realmente não funcionará e isso você não conseguirá resolver com um código batch e sim com o administrador da rede/servidor :)

Answer (score 3):

Não é a solução para seu problema, mas pode lhe ajudar.

Existe um programa chamado Nmap, ele serve para escanear a rede e diversas outras funções referente a varredura de ips...

Segue o link do site: https://nmap.org/download.html#windows

Instalador: https://nmap.org/dist/nmap-7.40-setup.exe

Com o comando abaixo você obtêm todos os hosts que responderam:

```
nmap -sP 192.168.1.1/24 | find /i "scan report"
```

Você pode dar saída deste comando para um arquivo e depois fazer o loop nele através dos registros.

Exemplo de saída do comando:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.38
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.41
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.45
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.62
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.67
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.68
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.87
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.90
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.92
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.95
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.96
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.97
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.99
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.102
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.104
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.110
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.111
```

Answer (score 2):

Infelizmente, **não é possível** fazer isso numa rede comum.

Não existe nada na rede que vai te dizer quais os IPs existem. Mas mesmo se existisse, para saber se o endereço está online você precisaria fazer a menor comunicação possível com a máquina e aguardar a resposta para saber se ela está online.

Essa menor comunicação é o [ping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)).

Agora se o que você precisa é executar vários "pings" de maneira mais rápida, uma coisa que você pode fazer é criar uma aplicação que execute vários pings simultâneos e retorne pra você apenas os que forem bem sucedidos. Veja um exemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13492134/460775

Quando estamos lidando com infraestrutura, existem ferramentas próprias pra isso. Uma muito utilizada é o [Nmap](https://nmap.org/book/inst-windows.html).